# interpreting the negative and positive values of profile curvature map in GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, curvature

I would like to have help in interpreting the values returned by ArcGIS for profile curvature.
By reading this Esri's webpage (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/27/understanding-curvature-rasters/), it seems that negative values should correspond to profiles upwardly convex (fig. 16.20A).

Now, it seems counter intuitive to me, since I would imagine that negative values would best convey a sense of "concavity".

I was just wondering if that reference is correct or if some error (typo?) would account for that seemingly oddity.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.